# How can I shade cells between 'Prep to QR' based on action 'N' using VBA macros?

Tags: maven-shade-plugin

How to shade the cells from "Prep to QR" if action "N" is detected.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LHUqo.png)

Dim R As Range

Sub ShadeCells()

```
color "N", wdGray50
color "Y", wdNoHighlight
```

End Sub

```
Function color(text As String, backgroundColor As WdColorIndex)
    Set R = ActiveDocument.Range
       With R.Find
       Do While .Execute(FindText:=text, MatchWholeWord:=True, Forward:=True) = True
    R.Cells(1).Shading.BackgroundPatternColorIndex = backgroundColor
       Loop
    End With
End Function
```